# NicEditor doesnot work properly in mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, nicedit

I have got a problem when using nicEditor for my textarea editors in mvc project.

Here is the 2 view pages that I have created.From the First View I pass route values to the Second view

```
   <ul class="mar">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <li class="mar" style="list-style-type:none">
                    <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:small">

                            <a  id="arrow_@item.thread.MessageID" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" style="text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;color:dimgray" onclick="toggle(@item.thread.MessageID)"></a>
                        <h3 class="mar" style="display:inline-block;"><a href="@Url.Action("GetMessage", "Home", routeValues: new{id=thread.Title.MessageID})" style="text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer">@item.thread.Title</a></h3>
                    </div>
       <li>
       </ul>
```

Second View

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
</script>
      <h2>GetMessage</h2>
      <textarea style="width:900px"></textarea>
```

Here second view displays the niceditor(textarea) without its images inbuild with the nicEditor[image]

When I remove the passing parameters from the First View,then it works Fine..

[image]

I need to know Why it happens like that???

Answer (score 0):

Use the developer tools of your browser and watch the network view, why the nicEditoricons.gif not loaded, is a path problem. Use the option iconsPath to set the right one.
And please, take a look in the manual of nicedit.

```
var NicEditconfig = {
   iconsPath : '/img/nicEditorIcons.gif',
   buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','ol','ul']
};
```

Comment: Yes,there is 404 error on the image node..But don't know the reason.i found the above code in the .js file.it is like                                               var NicEditorconfig = {
   iconsPath : '../nicEditorIcons.gif',
   buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','ol','ul']
}; How can I solve the problem??

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the path manually

First, check the console to find the current request path. If the request path is wrong, then configure it
HTML

```
 <textarea id="textAreaNiceEditor" style="width: 100%;">
        Some Initial Content was in this textarea
    </textarea>
```

JS Code

```
<script src="~/Content/NiceEditor/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
        new nicEditor({ iconsPath: '../../../Content/NiceEditor/nicEditorIcons.gif' }).panelInstance('textAreaNiceEditor');
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

> '../../../Content/NiceEditor/nicEditorIcons.gif'

Change this path value based on your gif location.

> Make sure that you use are using same textarea id in JS code. Above case the id value is textAreaNiceEditor